# Differences between 栽培する, 作る, and 育てる for "grow"?

Tags: word-choice, nuances, synonyms, transitivity

I'm trying to find the best word for "grow" something in a garden. This includes the transitive: "grow potatoes", "grow my own tea leaves" - and also the intransitive, "lots of weeds are growing in my yard."

For the transitive use, 3 words come up most commonly: 栽培する, 作る, and 育てる. 栽培する seems like the most technically correct word, but I can't tell if it has too formal of a nuance.

What's the best word choice here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess you can use all three without sounding too odd in gardening contexts.

- 作る is more common for something edible and may imply growing for crops
- 育てる may be preferred for flowers (バラを作る is a bit odd).
- 栽培する is more neutral. It is formal, but usual enough for normal conversation.

For 'weeds are growing', the most common phrase is 雑草が伸びる.